# ASA FTP Special Character in password issue

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I am trying to copy a show tech from an ASA to a remote server via FTP. 
My issue is that the password I am providing has a '@' and it is being interpreted incorrectly by the CLI. I have tried putting a  '\@' but the command still fails.

Anyone have any luck with this?

This works

```
  show tech-support file ftp://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ASA-SHOW-TECH
```

This Does not work

```
  show tech-support file ftp://username:p@ssword@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ASA-SHOW-TECH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem like it is supported, so the work around is to just change the password that does not have the @ special character if you need to automate the process.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that the device is interpreting the first `@` as the delimiter between the credentials and the FTP server address.

Perhaps configuring the username and password in global-configuration mode and then redirecting the `show tech` without specifying the credentials would do the trick. Otherwise, and I know this is a wimpy solution, changing the password to not include that one character may be the easiest and perhaps most secure way of working around this issue.

Comment: Can you specify how you set ftp username and password in the global config? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if it is the same syntax on an ASA, but on a Cisco router you use the commands `ip ftp username` and `ip ftp password` in global configuration mode to set a default username and password for FTP connections.

Answer (score 0):

On IOS you can enter control-v to escape the next character. This lets you enter a question mark without pulling up help. Don't if that works on ASA but might be worth a try.

Comment: This is ASA not IOS

Comment: That might explain why I said "Don't know if that works on ASA"...

Answer (score 0):

This works for ios not sure if it will work for the ASA

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/9945506/entering-question-mark-ios-command

Comment: Please consider adding more details to this answer so it remains useful even if the linked document is removed or changes.